# Intend not to fulfill Krias Hatorah

Tags: torah-reading, minyan, kavana-intent

May one have in mind not to be yoitzeh krias hatorah in a minyan that he is participating in order to be metzaref for another minyan later?

For example (according to the opinion that on Mon,Thu you only need 3 people who haven't heard kriah to make another minyan of kriah provided you have another 7 to be mashlim the 10) can someone who is part of a 730 shacharis minyan have in mind not to be yoitzeh the kriah if he knows at 830 they will need him to be one of the three who havent heard kriah yet?

Thanks

Comment: Can you source your premise that "on Mon,Thu you only need 3 people who haven't heard kriah"? Doing so will, among other things, give people a starting point of where to look for the answer to your question.

Comment: Why would this be different to any other mitzvah?

Comment: Are you assuming that there is an individual chiyuv of Krias HaTorah to begin with?

Comment: I think we can have this question while avoiding the question of whether Kriss hatorah is a personal chiyuv or not if for example everyone present requires an Aliya or another example.

Comment: And as for sources see the Shaarei Rachamim (one of the נושאי כלים of the שערי אפרים) who discusses this at length

Comment: The Mishna Berura Siman 589:11 says one can do this by Tekias Shofar.   (יא) אם כבר יצאו - וע"כ י"א דיתקע להם קודם שישמע התקיעות בביהכ"נ אבל במ"א מסיק בשם מהרי"ל שלא יתקע בשלשה שעות ראשונות משום דאז מיפקד דינא ואין כדאי לתקוע ביחידות אלא יתקע להן אחר תקיעות ביהכ"נ והם יברכו לעצמן *או שיכוין בלבו שלא לצאת *בתקיעות ביהכ"נ ואז יוכל אח"כ ג"כ לברך בשבילן:

Answer (score 0):

The underlying question is if one has in mind not to fulfill a mitzvah, regardless why he wants to do it, does it work?

The answer to that is yes. See Biur Halachah 60:4 "י"א שאין מצות צריכה כוונה " at the very end of the paragraph.

Comment: This assumes leining is a mitzva that needs intent to fulfill. R' Moshe Soloveichik held that a baal kriah who intended not to fulfill the obligation of someone in the congregation still fulfilled it anyway because you don't need intent here.

Comment: I am not sure that your comparison is accurate. When the baal koreh reads, he is doing an act which shows that he doing the mitzvah of areyvos and is motzee the listener and your source says that this intention won't ruin it. But in this question, the person will passively do nothing and have intent not to be yotzey krias hatorah. I think you need a better source than that.

Comment: @Geltman I need a better source to post an answer, but not to doubt your answer. Your post is insufficient at proving all the relevant assumptions necessary to answer the question.